# Wrap iframes/embeds, but do it before oEmbed happens

Tags: oembed

I am trying to wrap any iframe/embed in my content with some Facebook Instant Articles friendly code (only for that feed). I have it working, but it adds this code to oEmbed output as well which adds in a wrapper that is not needed (since the Facebook Instant Articles already handles oEmbed embeds).

Basically, how can I get the wrap on iframes/embeds to happen before the oEmbed stuff happens?

Below is the code I have:

```
function wrap_iframe( $content ) {
    if (is_feed( INSTANT_ARTICLES_SLUG )) {
        // Match any iframes or embeds
        $pattern = '~<iframe.*</iframe>|<embed.*</embed>~';
        preg_match_all( $pattern, $content, $matches );
        foreach ( $matches[0] as $match ) {
            $wrappedframe = '<figure class="op-interactive"><iframe>' . $match . '</iframe></figure>';
            $content = str_replace($match, $wrappedframe, $content);
        }
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wrap_iframe' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress embed the URLs on same filter with priority of 8

in [`/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php#L34)

```
// Attempts to embed all URLs in a post
add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'autoembed' ), 8 );
```

and you are parsing content after it with priority of 10 then defiantly you will get the parsed output.

You just need to do it early before WordPress embed URLs

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wrap_iframe', 5 );
```

Comment: This works perfect. Guess I should have known that it was just a matter of giving it a higher priority. Thanks!

Comment: Spoke too soon... after clearing the cache, etc. I noticed that it made the content empty for some reason when I viewed a regular post in my templates that were not in the feed (seems like the feed part worked fine though).

Comment: Do I need to add an else statement in the function to just return $content even if it is not a feed?

Comment: No need for else, just put the `return $content;` statement outside the `if` block. In filters value should be return always even if modified or not! @KKranzo

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific filter for this: `embed_oembed_html`.

```
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', function($html) {
    return '<figure class="op-interactive">'.$html.'</figure>';
}, 11);
```

Source: [Wordpress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_oembed_html/)